# Do something after attribute value got assigned

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I would like to do some mapping after the members have been set by angular dart:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'travel-step',
    templateUrl: 'packages/TravelPlanner/travelstep/travel_step_component.html',
    useShadowDom: false,
    publishAs: 'cmp')
class TravelStepComponent {
  // Deprecated but impossible to replace, since the new syntax is not ready
  @NgTwoWay('step')
  TravelStep step;

  TravelStepComponent() {
    // step is null at the moment
  }
}
```

I'm using angular v. 0.12. When the constructor is called, step is still null. 
I could do it with a watch expression but I only want to do it once, so this workaround is not how I want to do it.

Comment: I just want to mention that assigning values to attributes/fields has usually nothing to with dependency injection. DI is done manually by code like `injector.get()` or by instances created by the injector where DI assigns values to constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `AttachAware` and put your code into the `attach()` method.
Similar behavior can be achieved by implementing `ShadowRootAware`  and `onShadowRoot()`.

You need to give Angular some time to evaluate the bindings and assign the values. Use one of these methods according to your requirements.

Sometimes it might help to (additionally) wrap your code into a

```dart
new Future(() {
  your code here
});
```

to delay the execution of your code.

Another approach is to implement a setter and execute your logic there

```dart
@NgTwoWay('step')
TravelStep _step;
TravelStep get step => _step;
set step(TravelStep s) {
  // your code here
  _step = s;
  // or here
}
```